# Latex - How to refer to the item's TEXT inside enumitem

Tags: latex, enumerate

I'm using enumitem to enumerate my variables list.

I have a variable list like:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item My First Cool Variable \label{var:myvar1}
\item My Second not so Cool Variable \label{var:myvar2}
\item My Third so so \label{var:myvar3}
\end{enumerate}
```

When I cross-reference one of these items, I get the list key. For example,

```
Let us reference \ref{var:myvar2} and then my other variable \ref{var:myvar3}
```

Gives:

```
Let us reference 2 and then my other variable 3
```

What I'd like is to not only be able to obtain the list key, but also the whole item text, so the output could be like:

```
Let us reference My Second not so Cool Variable and then my other variable My Third so so
```

The goal is to be able to write the variable name only once, and not changing everywhere if ever the variable name is modified to something more specific.

Any ideas? I've taken a look into enumitem-zref but I couldn't find what I was looking for :/

Comment: Follow the instructions listed in [Reference plain text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54854/5764).

Comment: I did see that answer from 3 years ago. I was kinda hoping they had come up with a cleaner way by now. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Using some ideas from [Macro to capture until end-of-line as argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127005/5764), you can capture the contents following an `\item`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127005/5764
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{wordenumerate}{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \let\olditem\item
    \def\item##1\item{\dosomething{##1}}%
    \expandafter\@empty\BODY\item
  \end{enumerate}%
}

\let\oldlabel\label
\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{%
  \def\elvitaluz@arg{#1}%
  \ifx\elvitaluz@arg\elvitaluz@stop
    \end{enumerate}
    \expandafter\env@ignore   % to end the recursion
  \else
    \def\label##1{\def\@textlabel{##1}\let\label\relax}% Capture \label
    \olditem #1
    \ifx\label\relax
      \def\label##1{\@bsphack\@esphack}%
      \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% % what to do with #1
      \expandafter\oldlabel\expandafter{\@textlabel}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\item         % to continue the recursion
  \fi}

\edef\elvitaluz@stop{\noexpand\end{enumerate}\noexpand\env@ignore\space}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{wordenumerate}
  \item First
  \item Second\label{second}
  \item \label{third}Last
\end{wordenumerate}

Item~2 is \ref{second}. Item~3 is \ref{third}.

\end{document}
```

The use of a new environment `wordenumerate` is suggested, as an entirely different `\label`-`\ref` is at play. I would not suggest nesting this environment in anything else (also because of the use of [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ)).